# Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010 not valid

Tags: windows, certificate, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-security

On my Windows 8.1 machine (freshly installed), the **Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010** certificate is listed as not valid (as can be seen on the screenshot below).

[image: Not valid certificate properties page]

On the other hand, my Windows 10 machine shows this:

[image: Valid certificate properties page]

What can be the reason for such behaviour?

Comment: I see the same thing on my Windows 8.1 machine.  Neither Windows 7 nor Windows 10 seem to be affected.